# Random Ad-pops in Chrome and Firefox even with popup-blockers

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, security, malware

Some malware has crept into my ubuntu 16.04 LTS system (latest updated) which modifies source of web page, inserts this code in  section, in both Firefox and Chrome (both latest). This changes behavior of any javascript click in the web page to an ad-popup.

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="http://www.toponclick.com/a/display.php?r=1553359&amp;_=1494685778371&amp;treqn=172733714&amp;runauction=1&amp;crr=84119e388a96c5d1b150,,g2TPNpyK_84T9-yPP-aHNpy--5kbfuyTv_lfsu-Pu4lbv2RXqs6jP956P_i3u4k7_4iXu96nL4gDe0lKb0lKr1kK75jP-_052a77f1b12cc82f2600&amp;cbrandom=0.2537268017023072&amp;cbtitle=Maruti%20Car%20Price%2C%20New%20Car%20Prices%20in%20India%2C%20New%20Cars%20in%20India&amp;cbiframe=0&amp;cbWidth=1535&amp;cbHeight=773&amp;cbdescription=Submit%20a%20few%20details%20-%20select%20your%20city%2C%20the%20car%20model%20of%20your%20choice%20and%20get%20Maruti%20new%20car%20price%20in%20your%20location&amp;cbkeywords=new%20car%20prices%2C%20car%20price%20in%20india%2C%20maruti%20car%20price%2C%20maruti%20Suzuki%20car%20prices%2C%20maruti%20car%20prices%2C%20car%20prices%20in%20india&amp;slt=1"></script>
```

I have reset both firefox and chrome but it did not help. I checked running processes and none seem suspicious to me. I purged both firefox and chrome but after re-install it has resurfaced again.

I'd looking for suggestions - where could such malwares be stored in the system? Or anyone has similar problem and have solved it, pls share your solution.

PS: I'm scanning with ClamAV anti-virus. Will update results if it's useful.

**UPDATE**

Problem comes for other user sessions as well. In fact, it shows up in windows partition as well.

I hard reset my router but still the problem persists!!

Problem shows up in macbook too.

**FINAL**

Certainly the problem is not with Ubuntu or Chrome or Firefox. I'd keep this question alive so that others who face similar issues can pin-point their problem correctly, instead of ending up formatting their system unnecessarily.

Comment: It's most likely `advertising` code injected into you browsers from a tracking.  In Firefox install `adblock` plugin, in Chrome you will update your privacy setting in Chrome's advance settings. Then if `sync` is turned on disable it... Clamav won't find a thing

Comment: [here](http://www.removemalwarevirus.com/step-by-step-solution-to-delete-toponclick-com-complete-removal-guide) is a step by step guide to remove this on windows. I'm not sure what other places it infects in linux. Please share if you find a solution.

Comment: Try it on a different user account. If it happens there too, throw away the whole system installation and reinstall from scratch. Once any malware has dug in that deep, you can never know if you were able to remove all traces or if they still have another ace up their sleeves to restore their infection. If the other user does not have the problem, consider throwing away your current user account and start over with the new account. Always make sure to have backed up your important data before nuking anything though.

Comment: @SirajusSalekin thanks I checked the soln. I have already tried those options. It did not fix it.

Comment: @ByteCommander ad clicks appear for other users on the system too :-(

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti Sorry for the bad news, but that means that either the infection reached root level on your system, which is required to spread across multiple user accounts, or the other option could theoretically be that the ads are injected on the way between webserver and your computer, which would likely mean a router infection. So maybe before you really do the reinstall, just boot the live system from the Ubuntu installation medium ("Try Ubuntu without installing") and see whether the ads appear there too. If so, it must be the router. If the live session is clean, you should reinstall.